# android webview autocomplete/autofill

Tags: android-studio, webview

I am creating a web app which requires a login. It seems my webview autofill/autocomplete does not work. Is this feature disabled by default? In my search through the web I have found many posts asking how to disable this feature, leading me to believe that it is enabled by default. My credentials are remembered and autofilled fine when testing my web app in chrome for android. I have also loaded gmail in my webview and tested to see if autofill worked, and I still could not get it to work. My app is set for SDK 18 and up.

Thanks